# Hiding then show NavigationBar shifts the view to the bottom

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm probably missing something,

I have a navigation controller that I hide on tap (either with `hidesBarsOnTap` or `setNavigationBarHidden()`).

On the 1st tap, it hides itself and on the second it shows itself.

The problem is that on the second tap the view of my ViewController shifts to the bottom (frame.origin.x goes from 0 to 64) then stays always switches from 0 to 64.

Any idea why ?

Btw : My view has 4 constraints, Top & Bottom are linked to the Layout Guides.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets" option:

[image]